# downgrade min sdk version results too many errors on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Actually I'm new to Android and I built my project targeting version API 25, compile 25, min 25 version, and now i need my app to be accessible for more devices like sdk 14!

I changed min SDK version to 14 and it raised lots of errors.

> Note that I'm using RecyclerView, DrawerLayout, FloatingActionbar and BigContentNotification in my application!

Comment: Why did you find it necessary to post a large unreadable capture of your **entire desktop**? Why are you posting an image at all instead of your code? Code and error messages are both text. And common sense says that the way to downgrade the SDK version is to start by removing the code that references things from the  higher version that don't exist in the lower version.

Comment: Because it is driving me crazy and i hope it can help to tell me the version problems or maybe sdk problems! @KenWhite

Comment: That's no excuse. Images should be used only when the issue cannot be demonstrated any other way, and even then should be as small as possible so that they're mobile-device friendly, not a dump of your entire screen with all of that wasted whitespace to the right. Images of code are useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons to avoid them.

Comment: @KenWhite ok. Im sorry. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used min SDK 19 and trying to install in android 4.0.4!!
But actually there was some points too:

- Use that library's versions that are Compatible (same) with your target api (Recommended)
- If you put wrong(Incompatible) versions together, Your application might crash; so it's better to read [This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) first